# disable history substitution "preview" in zsh

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

in bash, if i enter:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd !$
```

bash substitutes */tmp/foo* for the bang-dollar, **and executes the command**

if i do the same in zsh, zsh fills in /tmp/foo for the bang-dollar and shows me the resulting command, pausing to let me again hit  before executing:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo           
cd !$     
cd /tmp/foo # command prompt at the end of this line
```

but i don't want to do see a preview, i want it to do what bash did.

is there a way to un-preview in zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have the `HIST_VERIFY` option set; you can disable it with

```
setopt NO_HIST_VERIFY
```